# How do I check whether I have GRUB installed in my machine or not?

Tags: grub2

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a dual boot with Windows 10. However, I cannot boot it when I start the machine. I don't know if I have installed GRUB or not.

How do I check whether I have GRUB installed in my machine?

Comment: Hello. Please edit the question and make it clear. This statement from your question. < I can not boot it when start.> Boot what? When what starts?

Comment: Which System do you directly boot? Ubuntu or Windows 10?